# Decryption of AES-CBC-256 in Java

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, aes

I need to encrypt a value in Java using AES CBC 256 but I am unable to decrypt it in NodeJS:

The cyphered string is generated with the following code:

```
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
String result = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(cipher.doFinal(test));
```

and decrypted with this one:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var mykey = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', key);
var mystr = mykey.update(value, 'hex', 'utf8')
```

but the code returns an error:

```
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Decipher.final (internal/crypto/cipher.js:104:26)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:12:16
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:74:29)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:182:6)
    at evaluate (/run_dir/repl.js:133:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/run_dir/repl.js:116:5)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:11)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
```

I assume it has something to do with the padding strategy but I can not find any documentation on the one applied by NodeJS.
What is the equivalent padding in Java Cypher corresponging to the one provided by the cripto package in NodeJS?

Comment: You're not handling the IV...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) requires an **Initialization Vector (IV)** to be pressent when encryptin the first block. In the Java implementation of **AES** you can provide this when you Initialize the Cipher, or you can let Java generate one for you. In your case Java have genereted an **IV** for you. As this is needed when you decrypt, you need to grab this and pass it along with the encrypted data (this ought to be random, but don't need to be kept secret). Use the `Cipher.getIV()` methode to get it.

In **NodeJS** there is a variant of the `crypto.createDecipher()` where you can provide this **IV** called `crypto.createDecipheriv()`